# Here Maps Geocoder Autocomplete API search without accents

Tags: here-api

I'm using Here Maps Geocoder Autocomplete API and when i'm trying to search a Greek location without accents the suggestions response is empty.

For example when i'm searching for "Θεσσαλονίκη" the response returns an array with some suggestions. But when i'm searching for "Θεσσαλονικη", with no accent in the third letter from the end, the response returns an empty array.

Is there any possibility that i'm missing something in the API or the functionality that i described is not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the exact query you are using for us to help you better. From the given data, we tried using autocomplete api and it works fine

**Sample query:**

```
https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?at=41.8369,-87.684&q=Θεσσαλονικη&Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.5&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx
```

**Sample Response:**

```
results: [ { Thessaloniki (Θεσσαλονίκη) }{ Κρατικός Αερολιμένας Θεσσαλονίκης }{ Kentro Thessalonikis }{ KTEL Thessalonikis }{ Θεσσαλονίκη }{ Θεσσαλονίκη }{ Θεσσαλονίκη }{ Θεσσαλονίκη }{ Θεσσαλονίκη }{ Megaro Mousikis Thessalonikis }{ Θεσσαλονίκη }{ Θεσσαλονίκη }{ Dimarcheiako Megaro Thessalonikis }{ Archaiologiko Mouseio Thessalonikis }{ Θεσσαλονίκης }{ Θεσσαλονικης }
```

Edit: Geocoder autocomplete API helps you to complete addresses to you. When you search for 
1) Θεσσαλονίκη is does match to the full word and get the relevant results. 
2) Θεσσαλο is tries to get relevant matches by completing the word 
3) Θεσσαλονικη it tries to match to the full word and doesnt find any relevant results.

It doesn't work the same way how it does on a map where it suggests typos in the address. We have discussed something similar in this post - [Here-API: Order of search query seems to matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54036583/here-api-order-of-search-query-seems-to-matter/54038347#54038347).

We suggest you to try autosuggest as given above, to see if it fits your usecase.

Comment: I'm using Geocoder Autocomplete API, not Places (Search) API.

The query: https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?query=%CE%98%CE%B5%CF%83%CF%83%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B7&maxresults=5&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx

The response: {"suggestions":[]}

Comment: Indeed your recommendation helped me to succeed my goal. Thank you very much for your help.